# How do I re-write this SQL statement to accept the array variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making an API call to retrieve `user_name`'s from my database.

My first step is to make a call to retrieve all the `player_id's`. They are stored in `$communityPlayersIds` and currently output as below:

> ["2","31","31","32"]

I now want to make a second call to the database to fetch the `user_name`'s of the id's that match.

```
$communityPlayerNames = array();
$communityPlayerNames = $dao->getPlayerNames($communityPlayersIds);
```

I have looked into it and seen I should use an IN command something like this:

```
public function getPlayerNames($player_ids)
{
$returnValue = array();

$sql = "SELECT user_name\n"
. "FROM users\n"
. "WHERE id IN ( '".$player_ids."')";

  $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   if(!empty($row)){
      $returnValue[] = $row;
   }
   }
 }
    return $returnValue;
}

}
```

However this isn't working and returns this:

> [{"user_name":null}]

If I echo ($sql) I get this:

> SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE id IN ( '2,31,31,32')

Which looks correct does it not?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should look at table valued parameters....and while you are at it you should research how to use parameterized queries in php before bobby tables comes to visit.

Comment: It says your syntax is incorrect, so why don't you at least dump the SQL statement string to see what it looks like. Also, it's not clear how you build `$player_ids` from the given JSON, so that's probably a hint.

Comment: so I need to dump the "player_id" part of the `$communityPlayersIds` array and rebuild it with just the remaining id numbers?

Comment: I've updated the question with my new function and the progress I've made.  I've stripped out 'player_id' and now have an array with just the numbers.  Thought the function is not returning any values?

Answer (score 3):

You essentially want your final query to look like this

```
Select user_name from users where id in (2,31,31,32)  -- dupe 31 does no harm
```

Make sure your series of IDs are inside parentheses `IN ($player_ids)` and not just a single quote `IN '$player_ids'`

Comment: that query is already in the given code, but what's not shown is how to get those numbers given the JSON

Comment: @JeffPuckettII  Unless I'm reading this wrong his syntax is IN '".$player_ids."'";  ... no ().

Comment: I've updated the question with my new function and the progress I've made. I've stripped out 'player_id' and now have an array with just the numbers. Thought the function is not returning any values?

Comment: @RDowns  try this in Chrome console   myArray = [12,150,32];myArray.toString()

Answer (score 0):

You can try building the IN-part of the SQL like this:

```
$returnValue = array();

$in_statement = "(";
foreach($player_ids as $player_id)
{
    $in_statement = $in_statement.$player_id->player_id.",";
}
rtrim($in_statement, ",");
$in_statement = $in_statement.")";

$sql = "SELECT community_players.player_id\n"
. "from community_players\n"
. "where community_players.community_id in ".$in_statement."";
```

So just the middle-part is new, where the $in_statement gets build. And in your SQL you have to change the "=" to "IN". You can generate the IN-part shorter, but this way you can easier see how it's done, so you can fit it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

in your code you put `'` after `in` which shows syntax error.
You can try

Assuming your
`$communityPlayersIds` has below value as array:

["2","31","31","32"]

if its not an array then convert it using `json_decode()`
and then try below query

```
$sql = "SELECT community_players.player_id\n"
. "from community_players\n"
. "where community_players.community_id IN (".join(",",$communityPlayersIds).")";
```

Comment: this line:  $in_statement[] = $player_id->player_id;  brings up this error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object.   If I put 'echo json_encode($player_id);' inside the loop i get {"player_id":"2"}{"player_id":"31"}{"player_id":"32"}